# Using the count function on third table in two table select statement in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, count, mariadb

I just spent a few hours reading through the MariaDB docs and various questions here trying to figure out a SQL statement that did what I want. I'm definitely not an expert... eventually I did get the result I expected, but I have no idea why it works. I want to be sure I am actually getting the result I want, and it isn't just working for the few test cases I have thrown at it.

I have three tables guestbook, users, and user_likes. I am trying to write a SQL statement that will return the user name and first name from users, post content, post date, post id from guestbook, and a third column likes which is the total number of times that post id from guestbook appears in the user_likes table. It should only return posts which are of type standard and should order the rows by ascending post date.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`user_id` int, `user_first` varchar(6), `user_last` varchar(7),
     `user_email` varchar(26), `user_uname` varchar(6))
;
    
INSERT INTO users
    (`user_id`, `user_first`, `user_last`, `user_email`, `user_uname`)
VALUES
    (0, 'Bob', 'Abc', 'email@example.com', 'user1'),
    (13, 'Larry', 'Abc', 'email@example.com', 'user2'),
    (15, 'Noel', 'Abc', 'email@example.com', 'user3'),
    (16, 'Kate', 'Abc', 'email@example.com', 'user4'),
    (17, 'Walter', 'Sobchak', 'walter.sobchak@shabbus.com', 'Walter'),
    (18, 'Jae', 'Abc', 'email@example.com', 'user5')
;


CREATE TABLE user_likes
    (`user_id` int, `post_id` int, `like_id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO user_likes
    (`user_id`, `post_id`, `like_id`)
VALUES
    (0, 23, 1),
    (0, 41, 2),
    (13, 23, 7)
;


CREATE TABLE guestbook
    (`post_id` int, `user_id` int, `post_date` datetime,
     `post_content` varchar(27), `post_type` varchar(8),
     `post_level` int, `post_parent` varchar(4))
;
    
INSERT INTO guestbook
    (`post_id`, `user_id`, `post_date`, `post_content`,
     `post_type`, `post_level`, `post_parent`)
VALUES
    (2, 0, '2018-12-15 20:32:40', 'test1', 'testing', 0, NULL),
    (8, 0, '2018-12-16 14:06:40', 'test2', 'testing', 0, NULL),
    (9, 13, '2018-12-16 15:47:55', 'test4', 'testing', 0, NULL),
    (23, 0, '2018-12-25 17:59:46', 'Merry Christmas!', 'standard', 0, NULL),
    (39, 16, '2018-12-26 00:28:04', 'Hello!', 'standard', 0, NULL),
    (40, 15, '2019-01-27 00:46:12', 'Hello 2', 'standard', 0, NULL),
    (41, 18, '2019-02-25 00:44:35', 'What are you doing?', 'standard', 0, NULL)
;
```

I tried a whole bunch of convoluted statements involving count and couldn't get what I wanted. Through what seems like dumb luck I stumbled into creating this statement which appears to be giving me what I want.

```
SELECT 
  u.user_uname, u.user_first, g.post_id, g.post_date,
  g.post_content, count(user_likes.post_id) AS likes
FROM
  users AS u, guestbook AS g
LEFT JOIN
  user_likes on g.post_id=user_likes.post_id
WHERE
  u.user_id=g.user_id AND g.post_type='standard'
GROUP BY
  g.post_id
ORDER BY
  g.post_date ASC;
```

Question:
Why does this count function appear to work?

The count function that I was able to get working is this, but it only works for hard coded post_id values.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE post_id WHEN 23 THEN 1 ELSE null END) FROM user_likes;
```

When I try to match the post_id from guestbook table by changing to this I get an incorrect value which appears to be the whole table of user_likes.

```
SELECT COUNT(case when guestbook.post_id=user_likes.post_id then 1 else null end) FROM guestbook, user_likes;
```

Adding a `GROUP BY guestbook.post_id` to the end gets me closer, but now I need to figure out how to combine that with my original select statement.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| COUNT(case when guestbook.post_id=user_likes.post_id then 1 else null end) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                          0 |
|                                                                          0 |
|                                                                          0 |
|                                                                          2 |
|                                                                          0 |
|                                                                          0 |
|                                                                          1 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is the output I want, which I am getting. I just don't trust that my statement is reliable or correct.

```
+------------+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
| user_uname | user_first | post_id | post_date           | post_content        | likes |
+------------+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
| user1      | Bob        |      23 | 2018-12-25 17:59:46 | Merry Christmas!    |     2 |
| user4      | Kate       |      39 | 2018-12-26 00:28:04 | Hello!              |     0 |
| user3      | Noel       |      40 | 2019-01-27 00:46:12 | Hello 2             |     0 |
| user5      | Jae        |      41 | 2019-02-25 00:44:35 | What are you doing? |     1 |
+------------+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
```

Fiddle of statement working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/968656/1/0

Comment: Since I don't know what you want, I can't fix your code.  It might help to provide the "correct" resultset.

Comment: Don't use implicit/comma-join syntax, and definitely don't inter-mix it with regular/explicit join syntax.

Comment: I edited the original question to include the expected output, which I do achieve with my original statement. I also looked up implicit vs explicit join syntax and it appears that the explicit (preferred?) simply uses a WHERE instead of a JOIN? Not sure how to formulate that here...

Comment: @Bryanisthebest - `u` and `g` are using the old syntax; please change.  You actually have a combination of the two forms (`FROM u, g JOIN ul ON WHERE u..g..`).  Ugh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` + `COUNT` -- A query first combines the tables as directed by the `JOIN` and `ON` clauses.  The result is put (at least logically) into a temporary table.  Often this temp table has many more rows than any of the tables being `JOINed`.

Then the `COUNT(..)` is performed.  It is counting the number of rows in that temp table.  Maybe that count is exactly what you want, maybe it is a hugely inflated number.

`count(user_likes.post_id)` has the additional hiccup of not counting any rows where `user_likes.post_id IS NULL`.  That is usually irrelevant, in which case, you should simply say `COUNT(*)`.

Please don't use the commalist form for joining.  Always use `FROM a JOIN b ON ...` where the `ON` clause says how tables `a` and `b` are related.  If there is also some filtering, put that into the `WHERE` clause.

If the `COUNT` is too big, put aside the query you have developed and start over to develop a query that does exactly one thing -- compute the county.  This query will probably use fewer tables.

Then build on that to get any other data you need.  It may look something like

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT foo, COUNT(*) AS ct FROM t1 GROUP BY foo ) AS sub1
    JOIN t2 ON t2.foo = sub1.foo
    JOIN t3 ON ...
    WHERE ...
```

Get that initial query that gets the right `COUNT`.  Then, if needed, come back for more help.

**As tried by Bryan**

OK, I made a few changes.

```
SELECT  u.user_uname, u.user_first,
        g2.post_id, g2.post_content, g2.post_date,
        sub.likes
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  g.post_id,
                SUM(g.post_id = ul.post_id) AS likes
            FROM  guestbook AS g
            JOIN user_likes AS ul
            WHERE  g.post_type = 'standard'
    ) AS sub
    JOIN  guestbook AS g2  ON sub.post_id = g2.post_id
    JOIN  users AS u       ON u.user_id = g2.user_id;
```

Indexes:

```
guestbook:  (post_type, post_id)  -- for derived table
guestbook:  (post_id)             -- for outer SELECT
users:  (user_id)
user_likes:  (post_id)
```

Notes:

- `ORDER BY` removed since it was useless in context.
- `COUNT..CASE` changed to shorter `SUM`.
- `JOIN ON` used

Since there is only one value coming from the derived table, this might work equally well:

```
SELECT  u.user_uname, u.user_first,
        g.post_id, g.post_content, g.post_date,
        ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM user_likes AS ul
            WHERE g.post_id = ul.post_id
        ) AS likes
    FROM  guestbook AS g
    JOIN  users AS u   USING(user_id);
    WHERE g.post_type = 'standard'
```

This involved lots of changes; see if it looks 'right'.  It is now a lot simpler.

Indexes are same as above.

Comment: I edited the original question to include the count statements I've tried. I am getting close with this, except I appear to be getting count values that are 8x what I want...
```SELECT u.user_uname, u.user_first, g.post_id, g.post_date, g.post_content, COUNT(CASE WHEN g.post_id=l.post_id THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS likes FROM users AS u, guestbook AS g, user_likes AS l, guestbook LEFT JOIN user_likes ON guestbook.post_id=user_likes.post_id WHERE u.user_id=g.user_id AND g.post_type='standard' GROUP BY g.post_id ORDER BY g.post_date ASC;```

Comment: @Bryanisthebest - JOIN+COUNT -- the JOIN builds a temp table with the combination of rows. _THEN_ the COUNT is done on this bloated table.  Hence the 8x.  This is why I have a subquery to _first_ do the `COUNT` on the single table, _then_ do  the `JOINs`.

Comment: Ok, I believe I found the count query that I need to use. ```SELECT guestbook.post_id, COUNT(CASE WHEN guestbook.post_id=user_likes.post_id THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS likes FROM guestbook, user_likes WHERE guestbook.post_type='standard' GROUP BY guestbook.post_id;``` This provides me a column with the count I want.

Comment: Incorporating that into the full query like this provides the correct output. Am I still using any outdated syntax? Is there a way to cleanup repeat table names? ```SELECT users.user_uname, users.user_first, guestbook.post_id, guestbook.post_content, guestbook.post_date, sub.likes FROM ( SELECT guestbook.post_id, COUNT(CASE WHEN guestbook.post_id=user_likes.post_id THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS likes FROM guestbook, user_likes WHERE guestbook.post_type='standard' GROUP BY guestbook.post_id ) AS sub JOIN guestbook ON sub.post_id=guestbook.post_id JOIN users on users.user_id=guestbook.user_id;```

Comment: @Bryanisthebest - I may have broken it, but see if either of my added formulations works.

Comment: Yes it appears that the latter one does provide the correct output and is clean enough for me to understand. When I sat down to write this I figured I'd knock it out fairly easily but quickly realized how inexperienced with SQL syntax I really am. Thank you for the help!